# Ruby method list: "unexpected kDEF, expecting $end"

Tags: ruby

I feel pretty dumb having to ask this, but it's had me stumped way too long. Attempting to run the following, I get

`finance.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected kDEF, expecting $end`

```
def get_sign(input)
 return "+" if input.include? "+"
 return "-" if input.include? "-"
end

def get_account_name(input)
 if input.split[0] == "new"
  return input.split.reject{|x| x == "new" or x == "account"}[0]
 else
  return input.split[0]
 end
end
```

If I wrap them in a class, it just expects `<, \n, or ;` instead of `$end`.

Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9 (via Macruby) give the same error. Removing the second method seems to get it working. Someone, please enlighten me; this seems like a really fundamental misunderstanding of something on my part.

Comment: Yup, this is it. Methods aren't even being called.

Comment: It's not common to use `return` in Ruby, and rarely necessary; your first method can be rewritten as: `def get_sign(input)\nif input.include? "+"\n"+"\nelsif input.include? "-"\n"-"\nend\nend` and you can simply remove the `return` keywords from your second method for better—and faster—code.

Comment: Your code compiles for me using MRI 1.8.7 on Linux.  How are you running it?  If you're just typing `./finance.rb`, you'll need a shebang as the first line (e.g. "#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8").

Comment: I don't get this error if I copy/paste your contents from this question into a new file. If you do so (copy/paste from this web page into a new file and save that) do you still get the error? If not, perhaps you have some garbage whitespace in your file?

Comment: Ugh. Retyping into a fresh document got it working, some stupid invisible character must have been messing it up.

Comment: That's right, Phrogz, thanks. I keep forgetting how nice Ruby treats us, lol.

Comment: For what it's worth, ruby usually has two space indentation, not one space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get this error if I copy/paste your contents from this question into a new file. If you do so (copy/paste from this web page into a new file and save that) do you still get the error? If not, perhaps you have some garbage whitespace in your file?

*Added as answer because another user may find this question with a similar problem and not read through all the comments to find the solution.*